# Linkage of a Static Function in a Namespace in C++

Tags: c++, static, namespaces, linkage

What is the linkage of a static function declared in a non-global namespace?

Example:

```
namespace foo {
  ...
  static void bar(int a) { }
}
```

Is this any different than a static method declared at the global namespace scope? Can someone point me to the place in the standard where this is laid out?

Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`static` when used in a function at namespace level means *internal linkage*.

The specific quote would be from 3.5 Program Linkage, paragraph 3:

> A name having namespace scope (3.3.6) has internal linkage if it is the name of
>
> - a variable, function or function template that is explicitly declared static; or, [...]

Comment: So if bar were declared at file scope, this counts as being declared in the default namespace, so for C++, file scope is namespace scope?

Comment: @anjruu: *file scope* is not a concept in C++, but anything that is not in any other scope is in the scope of the global namespace, so it is in namespace scope.